# Deleting multiple CKRecords at the same time

Tags: objective-c, xcode, icloud, cloudkit

I have been programming in objective-C for about a year now, but i am new to cloud kit. I can do simple things such as fetch, save and delete Records but I have not been able to find a way of deleting multiple Records at a time.
I tried a for loop but, although there were no errors, nothing was deleted.
heres some of the code:

```
      for (CKRecord* r in self.allRecords) {
        [[[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase] deleteRecordWithID:r.recordID completionHandler:^(CKRecordID *recordID, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error");
            }else
                NSLog(@"deleted");
        }];
    }
```

allRecords is an array containing the records which i need deleting but it does not delete any of the records.
Thanks

Comment: what is the reply/error you are getting?

Comment: There is no error and the delete log is called. The records are then queried and loaded into a tableview and there are the same amount of records

Comment: I agree with Trevor's response below. It seems the records ARE deleted correctly in CloudKit based on the fact you are getting a success response

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify (that is, save or delete) multiple records in one CloudKit round-trip, you need to use a `CKModifyRecordsOperation`: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKModifyRecordsOperation_class/index.html

You mention "allRecords is an array containing the records which i need deleting but it does not delete any of the records".

It's not clear whether you mean that the records aren't being deleted from CloudKit, or you mean that the records aren't being deleted from your `self.allRecords` array.

In case you're expecting the records to be removed from `self.allRecords`: they won't. That's your job to manage after examining the response from either the `CKModifyRecordsOperation` or the `deleteRecordWithID:completionHandler:` call in your snippet above.